# Create a java program to solve quadratic equations

Tags: java, applet, computer-science

Solving a quadratic equation

**I have the following written down so far. I am not sure on how to introduce the second method**

```
public static void main(string args[]){

}

public static  double quadraticEquationRoot1(int a, int b, int c) (){

}

if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c) == 0)
{
    return -b/(2*a);
} else {
    int root1, root2;
    root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
    root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
    return Math.max(root1, root2);  
}

}
```

Comment: Why return the max of the roots? Why not an array containing both roots?

Comment: http://www.hubberspot.com/2012/05/how-to-solve-simple-quadratic-equation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your code won't compile--you have an extra `}` after the start of `public static  double quadraticEquationRoot1(int a, int b, int c) ()`.

Secondly, you aren't looking for the correct input types.  If you want input of type `double`, make sure you declare the method appropriately.  Also be careful of declaring things as `int` when they could be doubles (for example, `root1` and `root2`).

Thirdly, I don't know why you have the `if/else` block--it would be better to simply skip it, and only use the code that is currently in the `else` part.

Finally, to address your original question: Simply create a separate method and use `Math.min()` instead of `Math.max()`.

So, to recap in code:

```
public static void main(string args[]){

}

//Note that the inputs are now declared as doubles.
public static  double quadraticEquationRoot1(double a, double b, double c) (){    
    double root1, root2; //This is now a double, too.
    root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
    root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
    return Math.max(root1, root2);  
}

public static double quadraticEquationRoot2(double a, double b, double c) (){    
    //Basically the same as the other method, but use Math.min() instead!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well why don't you try to use the same exact algorithms but then use Math.min in your return statement?

<s>Also, note that you're not taking into account whether or not $b$ is negative in your first if statement. In other words you simply return $-b / 2a$ but you don't check if $b$ is negative, if it isn't then this is actually the smaller of the two roots not the larger.</s>
Sorry about that! I misinterpreted what was going on xD

Comment: @Maesumi I was thinking completely improperly, I'm totally sorry! Does the first statement help though?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to just use Math.min. I am not sure what OP is asking though.

Comment: @Maesumi oop didn't realize you weren't the OP, hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
package QuadraticEquation;

import javax.swing.*;

public class QuadraticEquation {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter operand a :  ");
      double aa = Double.parseDouble(a);
      String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter operand b :  ");
      double bb = Double.parseDouble(b);
      String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter operand c :  ");
      double cc = Double.parseDouble(c);
      double temp = Math.sqrt(bb * bb - 4 * aa * cc);
      double r1 = ( -bb + temp) / (2*aa);
      double r2 = ( -bb -temp) / (2*aa);
      if (temp > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the equation has two real roots" +"\n"+" the roots are : "+  r1+" and " +r2);

        }
      else if(temp ==0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the equation has one root"+  "\n"+ " The root is :  " +(-bb /2 * aa));

        }

      else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the equation has no real roots !!!");
        }
    }        
}
```