# Java Storing variables from JTextField to use into Formula

Tags: java, swing, parsing, integer, jtextfield

I am having trouble storing variable from a JTextField into variable in order to perform the Quadratic formula.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    int a, b, c; //ax^2 + bx + c  

    //retrieving whatever is in textfield 
    String text1 = a1.getText();   //HERE IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE 
    String text2 = b2.getText();
    String text3 = c3.getText();


    //retrieving what is in tf and storing it 
    a = Integer.parseInt(text1);
    b = Integer.parseInt(text2); //TO PLACE INTO HERE 
    c = Integer.parseInt(text3);

    // compute the discriminate
    double discriminate = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);

    //compute roots
    double root1 = ((-1 * b) + discriminate) / (2 * a); //TO USE INTO HERE
    double root2 = ((-1 * b) - discriminate) / (2 * a);

    result.setText(Double.toString(root1 + root2));
}
```

Comment: What does "having trouble" mean?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: By the way, it's called a "discriminant", not a "discriminate".

Answer (score 2):

You should be outputting the two roots, but your final line is adding the roots and displaying the sum:

For example if you calculate two roots of , `root1 == 1` and `root2 == 3` your line

```
result.setText(Double.toString(root1 + root2));
```

Will display `4` where what you really want is something like `1,3`. The following line will do this

```
result.setText(root1 + ","+ root2);;
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the discriminant have a square root in it somewhere?  You current discriminant should be wrapped in a square root.

```
double discriminate = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);  // what you have
```

should be..

```
double discriminate = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));

                         ^^^
```

And as @Java Devil pointed out. Your code is currently adding the two values together instead of printing them individually

```
result.setText(Double.toString(root1 + root2));
```

Try this

```
result.setText("root1: " + root1 + ", root2: " + root2);
```

Comment: No, the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Quadratic_formula) "is the quantity under the square root sign in the quadratic formula."

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c)` is under the `Math.sqrt(..)`

Comment: `Math.sqrt()`:  "If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN."

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't overlook that fact that OP has no square root anywhere in his/her code.

Comment: `b^2 - 4ac` need to get rooted for the equation to result correctly

Comment: _"Math.sqrt(): "If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN."_. That's _exactly_ how the formula works :)

Comment: Take a look at all the quadratic formula questions on SO, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16888614/2587435)

Comment: I got the impression from the question that OP was having trouble reading the text fields - like maybe a scoping issue with `a1, b1, c1` or something.  Although the two mathematics errors are obviously a problem.  Until OP clarifies what the difficulty is, ("I'm having trouble with this line of code because my wife keeps distracting me when I try to type it")  I don't see how any answer can really be deemed correct.